# Python: Getting elements from a list of tuples, n at a time with unknown length of the list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm having a hell of a time printing out n elements at a time from a list of tuples of unknown length.

A deck of cards, for example:

```
a = [ ('2','c'), ('2','d'), ('2','h'), ('2','s'), ('3','c'), ('3','d'), ... ,('A',h'),('A','s') ]
```

The list in this example starts out at 52 length, but I am popping off elements. I want to print them out in groups of four (for this example), but I keep getting fouled up at the last group which can have  fewer than four elements.

Expected output after popping off a bunch of cards is:

```
('2','c'), ('2','d'), ('2','h'), ('2','s')
('3','c'), ('3','d'), ('3','h'), ('3','s')
...
('J','c'), ('J','d'), ('J','h'), ('J','s')
('Q','c'), ('Q','d')
```

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) might come in handy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
a = [ ('2','c'), ('2','d'), ('2','h'), ('2','s'), ('3','c'), ('3','d'), ... ,('A','h'),('A','s') ]

for e in range(0, len(a), 4):
    for i in a[e:e+4]:
        print i,
    print
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try a nested for loop. It's obvious, in retrospect. Thanks for the swift reply.

Answer (score 0):

add a check that says, `if len(a)<4 then pop len(a)-1`